# How to change the Ubuntu 19.04 GDM3 cursor theme?

Tags: gnome, login, themes, cursor

I have successfully changed login screen theme by editing `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` but the cursor remains the default Yaru cursor, is there a way to change the login screen cursor to my own theme that I use when I am logged in?

This only happens at login after reboot, i.e. when I wake from suspend or lock the PC, the cursor is the theme I want.

Answer (score 6):

While editing the file:

> /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults

You may change the cursor **theme**, **size** and **speed** as follows:

```
# Theming options
# ===============
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
cursor-theme='Bibata_Ice'
cursor-size=35
[org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse]
speed=-0.8
```

Here, I used the **Bibata_Ice** theme, with size **35** and speed **-0.8**.

Note that, the folder with the cursor theme has to be inside:

> /usr/share/icons

Comment: Please, also consider using `gsettings` type `man gsettings` in the terminal for help.

Comment: thank you @maciek!

Comment: I would have loved to find a complete answer using gsettings. I took the liberty to write my own answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I found out, from this source I found the command:

[cursor command](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/a4lg5g/change_mouse_cursor_on_the_login_screen/ebh7vcw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

It says:

```
EDIT The file /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

Add

`cursor-theme='cursor name here'`

below

```
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
```

To apply the change, the Debian wiki says:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

source:
[debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/GDM#Customizing_the_GDM_appearance)

Now reboot and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all available information together and researching a bit further here is what I came up with. No creating or editing of files and tedious research of command parameters. Just copy, paste and replace `${my_cursor_theme}` with your favorite theme.

## Set the theme

```
# You need machinectl, which is not installed by default
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends systemd-container

# Change the theme for the GDM user to ${my_cursor_theme}
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash -c \
 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme ${my_cursor_theme}'
```

I like KDE's dark Breeze cursor theme so I replaced `${my_cursor_theme}` with `breeze_cursors`.

## Finding a theme, and its name

If you don't know what cursor themes are installed on your machine—and which can be accessed by other users­—you can use `update-alternatives` to find out their names. Here is the output from my machine:

```
$ update-alternatives --display x-cursor-theme 
x-cursor-theme - manual mode
  link best version is /etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme
  link currently points to /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme
  link x-cursor-theme is /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
/etc/X11/cursors/Breeze_Snow.theme - priority 41
/etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme - priority 102
/etc/X11/cursors/core.theme - priority 30
/etc/X11/cursors/handhelds.theme - priority 20
/etc/X11/cursors/redglass.theme - priority 20
/etc/X11/cursors/whiteglass.theme - priority 20
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursor.theme - priority 90
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme - priority 30
/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme - priority 100
```

`update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` lets you choose the default cursor for other display managers, in case you didn't know that already.

## Reset the theme

If you want to reset the theme this is probably your best option:

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash -c \
  'gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme'
```

## Further resources I used

- https://garajau.com.br/2018/04/changing-gsettings-on-gdm-user

  - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#DConf_configuration

## Screen locking

> This only happens at login after reboot, i.e. when I wake from suspend or lock the PC, the cursor is the theme I want.

That is because what you are seeing is not your login manager or display manager but the lock screen of your desktop session. The Ubuntu developers took great efforts to make LightDM and now GDM3 and session lock screens look consistent in design, but they are separate components, — previously? — also involving a screensaver. There are—or were?—also some security implications which the [author](https://www.jwz.org/blog/2015/04/i-told-you-so-again/) of xscreensaver is getting quite annoyed of.